# How do I make a JavaScript data structure that maps characters to sets of characters?

Tags: javascript

Here's an interesting problem that, hopefully, you guys can help me figure out.

I need to use JavaScript to somehow create a map from each lowercase character (`'a', 'b', ..., 'z'`) to the set of characters that is a distance of 1 key away on the keyboard.

That is, I need a map

```
'a'--->{'q','w','s','z'}
'b'--->{'v','g','h','n'}
.
.
.
'z'--->{'a','s','x'}
```

(You might have to take a look at your keyboard to see what I mean.)

To test out how to do this, I tried creating an array of arrays

```
var A = {{'a',{'q','w','s','z'}, {'b', {'v','g','h','n'}};
```

on jsfiddle, but I get a red dot on that line when I run JSHint.

Any insight on why that might be?

Any alternative suggestion for how I can do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Your syntax is entirely invalid.

Comment: That isn't an array of arrays, its just some weird objects.  Arrays in JS are made with [], not {}

Comment: Whoops! I'm supposed to use [] instead of {}.

Comment: Amateur hour over here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
   var A = {
       'a': ['q','w','s','z']
       'b': ['v','g','h','n']
   }
```

Access like

```
   A['a']
```

which will retrieve array of q, w, s, z

Comment: Well, in fact `a` and `b` properties won't require single/double quot because this isn't JSON but just JavaScript objects.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: JSON is in fact JavaScript Objects. That's what the JS and O stand for.

Comment: @ColinDeClue JSON = JavaScript Object Notation. I know that. But if it's not JSON "as is", there's no reason to sorround property names in quots. What's best of JSON is that it's just a JavaScript object, but I'm going to point to the fact that JSON is a string, so JSON isn't a JavaScript object. The fact that it's *JavaScript notation* doesn't make it an object!

Comment: Double quotes (probably the standard), single quotes, or no quotes will all work for the key names in the object definition.  In this case I thought single quotes were appropriate since they are chars and it helps the clarity by making it easier to see how the accessing call A['a'] (where quotes are required) relates to the definition.  It is also what the OP used.